# How to combine images inside pdf by programme?

Tags: php, pdf, image-processing

Suppose there are two pdf files,each contains a single image.

How to combine them from left to right?

If there is no way to do in with PHP,you can do it in other languages as well.

Comment: I did,but SO didn't recalculate the rate.

Answer (score 0):

i think FPDI can do this
http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/

Comment: The functionality I need is http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/setapdf-merger/merge-join-combine-concatenate-pdf-files-with-php.html,but is there a free version?