# Combine PDF Blob Files from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, pdf, blob

How do I combine numerous PDF blob files into a single PDF so that can then be printed?

```
<?php  
include 'config.php'; 
include 'connect.php'; 

$session= $_GET[session]; 

$query = " 
 SELECT $tbl_uploads.username, $tbl_uploads.description,  
        $tbl_uploads.type, $tbl_uploads.size, $tbl_uploads.content,   
        $tbl_members.session 
 FROM $tbl_uploads 
 LEFT JOIN $tbl_members 
 ON $tbl_uploads.username = $tbl_members.username 
 WHERE $tbl_members.session= '$session'";  

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 

while(list($username, $description, $type, $size, $content) =  
  mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
header("Content-length: $size"); 
header("Content-type: $type"); 
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$username-$description.pdf"); 
} 

echo $content; 

mysql_close($link); 
exit; 

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ZIP Numerous Blob Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024765/zip-numerous-blob-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I combine numerous PDF blob files into a single PDF so that can then be printed?

You don't - at least not by simply combining the byte streams. You will need to process each file, and merge them into a new PDF document.

Some pointers, maybe one of the solutions, depending on the platform you're on, works for you:

- [PHP - How to combine / merge multiple pdf’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713701/php-how-to-combine-merge-multiple-pdfs)
- [How to combine images inside pdf by programme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641178/how-to-combine-images-inside-pdf-by-programme)
- [Need to merge multiple pdf’s into a single PDF with Table Of Contents sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418871/need-to-merge-multiple-pdfs-into-a-single-pdf-with-table-of-contents-sections)

Answer (score 0):

pdftk will merge multiple PDF files, as well as PDFsam..